# Discord.js | guild.owner.send() not working

Tags: discord.js

I searched something for a code that will make the bot message on the owner after it got invited and it's like this:

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
guild.owner.send('Thanks for invting me to the server!');
}):
```

But suddenly, it's giving me an error that says, cannot read propert send() of null, am I using old way to do this? if so, how do I make it work?

Does this means it can't find the owner of the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
  guild.owner.user.send('Thanks for invting me to the server!');
}):
```

If you were to console log `guild.owner` it would give you a json of the guild owner's id, username etc all within the `user` object, and to access this we need to do *`guild.owner.user`*

Comment: It gave me another error : (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: and also, I tried console.log(guild.owner) and also shows null

Comment: searching for guild members like this might give a few errors if you haven't yet turned on Server Member Gateway Intents, turn them on from the discord developer portal, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d91oc.png)

Comment: Head over to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/), sign in, click onto the bot your working on, go on to the `bot` tab from the side menu, scroll down, and you'll be on this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d91oc.png), simply switch `on` the `Server Member Intent` (This might fix your error, if not, update your discord.js module, `npm i discord.js`

Comment: @Arize Actually, [`Guild.owner`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=owner) *does* give you the GuildMember object. It's [`Guild.ownerID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=ownerID) that gives the ID

Comment: oh right, guild.owner.send doesn't work though? you would have to do guild.owner.user.send